# ASP.NET MVC - reason of different dateformat in the model of 2 similar MVC project with 2 similar DB

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have 2 similar ASP.NET MVC projects that read from 2 similar database, I don’t understand why in the model of project 1 during debug the native format of all the date in the model is `dd/mm/yyyy` (that for me is perfect) instead in model of project 2, the date format in the model is `mm/dd/yyyy`.

[image]

In the 2 projects, the code of the model, the view and the content of the controller are all the same.

I try to change this setting in `web.config`:

```
<globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-GB" />
```

to

```
<globalization  culture="it-IT"  uiCulture="it-IT"/>
```

but nothing changes.

I really don’t understand why I have date format `dd/mm/yyyy` like model number 1.

That depends on what?

Comment: I found that the language has turned since I integrated into my project it has become multilingual (Resource.it.resx and Resource.resx english)
does anyone know how to set the default date dd / MM / yyy in Italian?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, in multilanguage project, setting the English language also the **date format changes**, same thing for the Italian language... easy, but i didn't know.